# Convergence of Matrix Iterative

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

The method for solving $ \boldsymbol{x}$ in the iterative

$\boldsymbol{x^{n+1}}=\boldsymbol{Tx^n} +\boldsymbol{ C}$
is said to converge given that $\rho(\boldsymbol{T}) <1$
Also, a quick way of inspecting convergence is checking if $\boldsymbol{A}$ diagonally dominant.

Now, without tedious checking for the spectral radius of $\boldsymbol{T}$, what will happen if the matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is not diagonally dominant?

Comment: How does $A$ relate to your iteration?

Comment: I am solving for the solution to $\boldsymbol{Ax=b}$ using the iterative methods however, knowing if the solution converges by finding the eigenvalues is indeed more difficult, and time wasting compared to direct methods that are guaranteed to give nearly exact solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $Ax = b \Leftrightarrow x = Tx+C$, if the matrix is not diagonally dominant, the iteration may or may not converge, as this is just a sufficient condition. However, if it converges, it converges to the solution of $Ax = b$. So, you can just run your code with a stoping criteria based on the difference between consecutive iterations, and you'll probably be fine.